# Encryption Exception while loading application properties ( Java jasypt encryption)

Tags: java, maven, encryption, spring-3, jasypt

When trying to install a module using Maven, it throws up the following error:

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException:
Encryption raised an exception.
A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not 
installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength 
Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
```

The application properties are encoded like this:

```
app.check.url=ENC(sCO3322RNYdt3wPfO04GoaN9PijwJzUcn9rb4ggHymA\=)
```

And my spring configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- These always come from the file system in ./conf/appCtx -->
            <value>file:../application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration"/>
</bean>
<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES"/>
    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"/>
</bean>
```

And I have jdk 1.7 which does have the necessary JCE files for the encryption.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ILLA I didn't install anything extra. There are JCE files already present in my jdk's lib/security folder.

Comment: ok.Inside JCE files what are the jars there? mainly two jars needed for for installing jce? local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar.

Comment: @ILLA yes. those jars are there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you did not install jce,by default present in `lib\security`.But its not accessed or used.please download jce files and overwrite the existing files.see your error itself `you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)`

1. Follow this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/STONEHENGE/installing-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited-strength-jurisdiction-policy-files-6.html) and resolved your error.   [or]
   2.[org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException](http://technofes.blogspot.in/2011/10/orgjasyptexceptionsencryptionoperationn.html)

Comment: The link in step 1 is broken but the second one worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is not that you don't have the JCE. You do. But from your configuration, you are using a TripleDES algorithm and this requires installing the JCE "Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files", as the error says.

These files can be downloaded from Oracle's site (from the same page you download the JDK) and are distributed under a sligthly different license agreement, because you have to assure you are not from a "forbidden" country (Iran, N.Korea, etc)...

See this question at the Jasypt FAQ: http://www.jasypt.org/faq.html#no-unlimited-strength

Comment: Oh, and before a StackOverflow editor deletes this post for me resolving your issue without mentioning I'm the author of the thing: I am the author of jasypt. Now you know ;-)

Comment: That's interesting, why JDK7 includes a bad JCE jars along with it? because of limitation of export cryptographic technologyin US?